# Will it affect a site's google page ranks when a google sitemap is uploaded for the first time?

Tags: sitemap

**Short Version:** What are the chances that a site's various sub-pages' page-ranks will suffer if a proper google sitemap is submitted for the first time?

**Long Version:**
I'm working with a website that has some rather impressive organic page ranking on some of its sub-pages.

They've never submitted a sitemap to google, which has caused some of their primary sub-pages to be crawled rather infrequently (month-old data sometimes still shows on google search results, and a few of these are rather popular searches).

Furthermore, google still references some non-existing pages and visitors are visiting dead-links (I understand redirects would be ideal, where possible). The sitemap could let google know that those pages are no longer there.

Is there a way to communicate the information that can be communicated via google sitemaps without negatively affecting page-ranks throughout the site? I'm really concerned about shaking the boat too much and resetting some of the site's hard-earned Internet equity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that by submitting a sitemap to a search engine such as google you are just ensuring that they *know* about these other pages on your site and can work their way though the list.

Why do you think submitting a sitemap will affect your page rank?

I thought that Googles page rank was (as well as others) based on eigenvector centrality. This is why backlinks are so important, especially those from related high-volume/respected sites.

Comment: We share a similar understanding. I'd much rather eliminate all uncertainty. Thanks for your advice